# using nullptr instead of NULL when mixing C and C++

Tags: c++, c++11, sdl, nullptr

i have a very simple question...

i am using the SDL API which was written in C.  i am using C++.  my compiler supports the keyword nullptr, and I've been reading up on it.  it seems as if it is better to use rather than using the NULL macro.

when I call SDL_SetVideoMode, I assume it returns NULL on failure, so if i do:

```
SDL_Surface *test = nullptr;

if ((test = SDL_SetVideoMode(params)) == nullptr)
{
    // to-do code
}
```

will this accurately check if my optimization on the surface test was successful?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.  nullptr is comparable to and equivalent to a null pointer of any other pointer type.